# Request authentication on gatt server with BlueZ 5.37

Tags: linux, key, bluez, gatt, bluetooth-lowenergy

i am running on a rpi a gatt server(example-gatt-server modified) using BlueZ BLE stack and all runs just fine but i was wandering if anyone managed to set up a PIN authentication for the server. Haven't found any info online about this, i don't even know if the gatt profile supports pin authentication.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals

from optparse import OptionParser
import sys
import dbus
import dbus.service
import dbus.mainloop.glib

import gobject as GObject
import bluezutils

import config_file
import config_def

BUS_NAME = 'org.bluez'
AGENT_INTERFACE = 'org.bluez.Agent1'
AGENT_PATH = "/test/agent"

bus = None
device_obj = None
dev_path = None


def ask(prompt):
    try:
        return raw_input(prompt)
    except:
        return input(prompt)


def set_trusted(path):
    props = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", path), "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
    props.Set("org.bluez.Device1", "Trusted", True)


def dev_connect(path):
    dev = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", path), "org.bluez.Device1")
    dev.Connect()


class Rejected(dbus.DBusException):
    _dbus_error_name = "org.bluez.Error.Rejected"


class Agent(dbus.service.Object):
    exit_on_release = True

    def set_exit_on_release(self, exit_on_release):
        self.exit_on_release = exit_on_release

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def Release(self):
        print("Release")
        if self.exit_on_release:
            mainloop.quit()

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="os", out_signature="")
    def AuthorizeService(self, device, uuid):
        print("AuthorizeService (%s, %s)" % (device, uuid))
        authorize = ask("Authorize connection (yes/no): ")
        if (authorize == "yes"):
            return
        raise Rejected("Connection rejected by user")

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="o", out_signature="s")
    def RequestPinCode(self, device):
        print("RequestPinCode (%s)" % (device))
        set_trusted(device)
        return ask("Enter PIN Code: ")
        #return config_file.get(config_def.BLE_SECTION, config_def.BLE_PIN)

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="o", out_signature="u")
    def RequestPasskey(self, device):
        print("RequestPasskey (%s)" % (device))
        set_trusted(device)
        passkey = ask("Enter passkey: ")
        return dbus.UInt32(passkey)
        #return config_file.get(config_def.BLE_SECTION, config_def.BLE_PIN)

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="ouq", out_signature="")
    def DisplayPasskey(self, device, passkey, entered):
        print("DisplayPasskey (%s, %06u entered %u)" % (device, passkey, entered))

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="os", out_signature="")
    def DisplayPinCode(self, device, pincode):
        print("DisplayPinCode (%s, %s)" % (device, pincode))

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="ou", out_signature="")
    def RequestConfirmation(self, device, passkey):
        print("RequestConfirmation (%s, %06d)" % (device, passkey))
        confirm = ask("Confirm passkey (yes/no): ")
        if (confirm == "yes"):
            set_trusted(device)
            return
        raise Rejected("Passkey doesn't match")

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="o", out_signature="")
    def RequestAuthorization(self, device):
        print("RequestAuthorization (%s)" % (device))
        auth = ask("Authorize? (yes/no): ")
        if (auth == "yes"):
            return
        raise Rejected("Pairing rejected")

    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE, in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def Cancel(self):
        print("Cancel")


def pair_reply():
    print("Device paired")
    set_trusted(dev_path)
    dev_connect(dev_path)
    mainloop.quit()


def pair_error(error):
    err_name = error.get_dbus_name()
    if err_name == "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply" and device_obj:
        print("Timed out. Cancelling pairing")
        device_obj.CancelPairing()
    else:
        print("Creating device failed: %s" % (error))

    mainloop.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

    bus = dbus.SystemBus()

    capability = "KeyboardDisplay"

    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--adapter", action="store",
                  type="string",
                  dest="adapter_pattern",
                  default=None)
    parser.add_option("-c", "--capability", action="store",
                  type="string", dest="capability")
    parser.add_option("-t", "--timeout", action="store",
                  type="int", dest="timeout",
                  default=60000)
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if options.capability:
        capability = options.capability

    path = "/test/agent"
    agent = Agent(bus, path)

    mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()

    print("Capability:" + capability)

    obj = bus.get_object(BUS_NAME, "/org/bluez");
    manager = dbus.Interface(obj, "org.bluez.AgentManager1")
    manager.RegisterAgent(path, capability)
    #manager.RegisterAgent(agent, capability)

    print("Agent registered")

    # Fix-up old style invocation (BlueZ 4)
    if len(args) > 0 and args[0].startswith("hci"):
        options.adapter_pattern = args[0]
        del args[:1]

    if len(args) > 0:
        print("Custom Agent Registered")

        device = bluezutils.find_device(args[0],
                                    options.adapter_pattern)
        dev_path = device.object_path
        agent.set_exit_on_release(False)
        device.Pair(reply_handler=pair_reply, error_handler=pair_error,
                timeout=60000)
        device_obj = device
    else:
        manager.RequestDefaultAgent(path)
        #manager.RequestDefaultAgent(agent)
        print("Default Agent Registered")

    mainloop.run()
```

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: PINs have nothing to do with the server per se. Even gatt clients can require PIN authentication. The authentication occurs as part of pairing and is independent of the service(s). See the bluez Agent APIs for implementing pairing.

Comment: @kaylum: i know that pairing should be done independent of the gatt server but using Agent APIs work when trying to do like a simple pairing, then it asks me to input the PIN but when i try to connect directly to the gatt server with a BLE App(LightBlue on iOS), somehow the pairing is bypassing the bluez agent and the pin altogether and shows me the services on the device. My goal is to have a working pin for connecting to the gatt server too, or some kind of security authentication for that matter. Thank you

Comment: It's unlikely to be bypassing the bluez agent. There are different modes of pairing authentication as defined by the Bluetooth Specification. Not all modes require a PIN (namely Just Works pairing mode). It depends on how your agent is set up. But without knowing what your agent is or how you coded the agent it is not possible to be any more specific than that.

Comment: @kaylum: i've posted in the original section the py script which registers the Agent, thing is that when trying to see the gatt services with the lightBlue app, none of the script functions are called, as opposed to connecting without an ble app. Thanks for your help, appreciate